# Can't redirect after login?

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs

Getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of undefined` when trying to redirect after login. I have tried various methods on the router instance but it is undefined according to the console?

Login action (inside store):

```
login({ commit, dispatch }, { username, password }) {
    const querystring = require('querystring');

    this.$axios.$post('connect/token', querystring.stringify({
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        username,
        password,
        grant_type: 'password'
    }))
    .then(function (response) {
        dispatch('setToken', { 
            token: response.access_token, 
            expiresIn: response.expires_in 
        });

        this.$router.push({name: 'home' }); // this line is the issue
    })
    .catch(errors => {
      console.dir(errors);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to preserve `this` before calling it again inside `.then(...)` like:

```
login({ commit, dispatch }, { username, password }) {

    // Store `this` inside variable vm here
    const vm = this;
    const querystring = require('querystring');

    vm.$axios.$post('connect/token', querystring.stringify({
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        username,
        password,
        grant_type: 'password'
    }))
    .then(function (response) {
        dispatch('setToken', { 
            token: response.access_token, 
            expiresIn: response.expires_in 
        });

        // Use this for debugging purpose only
        console.log( vm.$router )

        // You can now access `$router` safely here now
        vm.$router.push({name: 'home' });
    })
    .catch(errors => console.dir(errors));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use `this` inside an regular function, that means that `this` is binded to the function and not the vue instance, change it to an arrow function:

```
.then((response) => {
        dispatch('setToken', { 
            token: response.access_token, 
            expiresIn: response.expires_in 
        });

        this.$router.push({name: 'home' }); // this line is the issue
    })
```

Other solution is to `.bind()` it:

```
.then(function (response) {
        dispatch('setToken', { 
            token: response.access_token, 
            expiresIn: response.expires_in 
        });

        this.$router.push({name: 'home' }); // this line is the issue
    }.bind(this))
```